# Finding convergence of sequence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Let ${X_n}$ be a sequence of independent random variables which takes values between $[0,1/3]$ Then show that $Z_n=X_1X_2...X_n$ converges to $0$ in probability.

What I think is that the sequence $Z_n$ converges to $0$ almost surely and almost sure implies convergence in probability. Am I right?

Comment: You don't even need independence for that. Just note $0 \le Z_n \le (\frac{1}{3})^n \to 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes right.

To show that the sequence converges almost surely to zero it is enough to show that the sequence is monotone and bounded (as it is)